# Can't Json.NET automatically handle value types with only implicit operators?

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

Here's my tiny custom value type class:

```
public struct PhoneNumber
{
    private readonly string _phoneNumber;

    public PhoneNumber(string phoneNumber)
    {
        _phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        // ... lots more will happen here to validate the phone number
    }

    public static implicit operator PhoneNumber(string phoneNumber)
    {
        return new PhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
    }

    public static implicit operator string(PhoneNumber phoneNumber)
    {
        return phoneNumber.ToString();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _phoneNumber;
    }
}
```

With implicit operators to/from strings and an overridden ToString method I would expect Json.NET should be able to serialize and deserialize an instance of this class.

However, doing this:

```
 var pn = new PhoneNumber("1234567890");
 var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pn);
```

... just returns an empty `{}`.

I'd rather not apply attributes to my value type class or implement a custom serializor.

Is there another convention I can follow to make Json.NET behave the way I like it to?

Comment: Your class doesn't have any properties, so its going to serialize as an empty object.  The implicit operators aren't going to affect Newtonsoft serialization.  You would need a custom type converter to serialize the class as a string.

Comment: Are you trying to avoid primitive obsession and have strong types instead of strings?

Comment: @VladimirSerykh, yes, that's exactly right. :)

Comment: @glenebob Structs are value types in c#.

Comment: Struct/Object/Value Type/Reference Type doesn't matter.  The Struct has no public properties so there is nothing to serialize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# is strongly-typed language. However, people usually using `string` values everywhere. In that case strongly-typed origin of the language doesn't help. Such issue is called [Primitive obsession](https://refactoring.guru/smells/primitive-obsession).

.NET provides `TypeConverter` to convert values between different types. `Newtonsoft.Json` uses type converters implicitly.

I came up with such solution:

**Strongly-typed interface**

First we define the interface to wrap the primitive value.

```
/// <summary>
/// Interface to make values strongly-typed with help of TypeConverters.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TInnerType">Inner type</typeparam>
public interface IStronglyTyped<out TInnerType>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Inner value.
    /// </summary>
    TInnerType Value { get; }
}
```

**Strongly-typed class**

Then we define the class that implements that interface.

```
/// <summary>
/// Strongly-typed value based on inner type (e.g. <see cref="string"/> or <see cref="System.Uri"/>).
/// If you need validation then implement ".IsValid()" method.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TInnerType">Type of the inner value.</typeparam>
public abstract class StronglyTyped<TInnerType> : IStronglyTyped<TInnerType>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Validation error format. Should contain "{0}" placeholder.
    /// </summary>
    protected virtual string ValidationErrorFormat => "'{0}' is not valid value";

    /// <summary>
    /// Inner value.
    /// </summary>
    public TInnerType Value { get; }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    protected StronglyTyped(TInnerType value)
    {
        Validate(value);

        Value = value;
    }

    private void Validate(TInnerType value)
    {
        if (!IsValid(value)) throw new StrongTypeException(GetType(), String.Format(ValidationErrorFormat, value));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Validates the value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>'true' if value is valid.</returns>
    protected virtual bool IsValid(TInnerType value)
    {
        return true;
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value.ToString();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks the equality of the inner values.
    /// </summary>
    protected bool Equals(StronglyTyped<TInnerType> other)
    {
        return string.Equals(Value, other.Value);
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
        return Equals((StronglyTyped<TInnerType>)obj);
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (Value != null ? Value.GetHashCode() : 0);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Implicit mapping to `string`.
    /// </summary>
    public static implicit operator string(StronglyTyped<TInnerType> obj)
    {
        return obj?.ToString();
    }
}
```

**Type converter**

After we have interface and class, we implement a generic type converter.

It would help to convert primitive string values to strongly-typed `IStronglyTyped<TValue>`.

```
/// <summary>
/// Generic type converter for converting `string` to `TValue` (and other way around).
/// </summary>
public class StringTypeConverter<TValue> : TypeConverter
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        return sourceType == typeof(string);
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
    {
        return destinationType == typeof(string);
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (value is string stringValue)
        {
            return CreateInstance(stringValue);
        }

        throw new NotSupportedException($"Can't convert `{value.GetType().Name}` to `{typeof(TValue)}`");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates instance of `TValue` from string value.
    /// </summary>
    protected TValue CreateInstance(string value)
    {
        return CreateInstanceInternal(value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates instance of `TValue` from string value.
    /// </summary>
    protected virtual TValue CreateInstanceInternal(string value)
    {
        if (typeof(IStronglyTyped<string>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TValue)))
        {
            return (TValue)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TValue), value);
        }
        else
        {
            var typeConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(TValue));
            return (TValue)typeConverter.ConvertFromString(value);
        }
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == typeof(string))
        {
            return ((TValue)value)?.ToString();
        }

        throw new NotSupportedException($"Can't convert `{typeof(TValue)}` to `{destinationType.Name}`");
    }
}
```

**Custom strongly-typed classes**

```
/// <summary>
/// Phone number.
/// </summary>
[TypeConverter(typeof(StringTypeConverter<PhoneNumber>))]
public class PhoneNumber : StronglyTyped<string>
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public PhoneNumber(string value)
        : base(value.Trim())
    {
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    protected override bool IsValid(string value)
    {
        if (value.Trim() == string.Empty)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Validation logic goes here

        return true;
    }
}
```

That approach would work with `Newtonsoft.Json` without additional configuration.

**UPD**

Additionally, if you'd like to use these strongly-typed classes with Entity Framework Core, you need to teach it how to transform them to `string` values. It doesn't use `TypeConverter` but uses `ValueConverter<,>`.

Therefore you need to define a custom value converter.

**ValueConverter**

```
public class StronglyTypedValueConverter<TStronglyTyped, TInner> : ValueConverter<TStronglyTyped, string>
    where TStronglyTyped : class, IStronglyTyped<TInner>
{
    private static readonly TypeConverter TYPE_CONVERTER = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(TStronglyTyped));

    public StronglyTypedValueConverter(ConverterMappingHints mappingHints = null)
        : base(
            stronglyTyped => FromStronglyTyped(stronglyTyped),
            value => ToStronglyTyped(value),
            mappingHints)
    {
    }

    private static string FromStronglyTyped(TStronglyTyped stronglyTyped)
    {
        var result = TYPE_CONVERTER.ConvertToString(stronglyTyped);
        return result;
    }

    private static TStronglyTyped ToStronglyTyped(object value)
    {
        var result = TYPE_CONVERTER.ConvertFrom(value);
        return result as TStronglyTyped;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it's not enough. You have to register custom conversions for each property of any of your custom types. It's much trickier.

Comment: Ping me if you need code snippet for Entity Framework Core.

Comment: That's a great answer - and very detailed too. Thanks. :)

Comment: Where is the StrongTypeException?

Comment: Could we get all the imports? They are kinda important ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the mention of "TypeConverter" at the bottom of the list here: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm#PrimitiveTypes.

Then I put together a very simple custom TypeConverter:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(Converter))]
public class PhoneNumber
{
    private readonly string _phoneNumber;

    public PhoneNumber(string phoneNumber)
    {
        _phoneNumber = _phoneNumber;
    }

    public static implicit operator PhoneNumber(string phoneNumber)
    {
        return new PhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
    }

    public static implicit operator string(PhoneNumber phoneNumber)
    {
        return phoneNumber.ToString();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _phoneNumber;
    }

    public class Converter : TypeConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
        {
            return sourceType == typeof(string);
        }

        public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
        {
            return destinationType == typeof(string);
        }

        public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
        {
            return value.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, if I have a class with my custom PhoneNumber property, it serializes the way I want it to:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public PhoneNumber PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Serialization:

```
var x = new MyClass
{
    PhoneNumber = new PhoneNumber("1234567890")
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x);
```

Output:

```
{ "PhoneNumber": "1234567890" }
```

Comment: That's right, `TypeConverter`. With my solution you can wrap `Guid` or `Uri` into `IStronglyTyped<>` to provide additional validation and more specific type. This fixed primitive obsession not only for `string` values but for other generally used "primitive" types.

Comment: @VladimirSerykh Thanks. You beat me to it by 3 minutes. Very impressive.